# AJAX request to Cloud Pages from 3rd page origin

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, ajax

I'm trying to use JS in my origin website to make an AJAX POST to a Cloud Page, that should then write the post data to a Data Extension. The process works well on Postman.

The goal is to retrieve data to be used by customers, and later POST it back to be written with some updates on a second Data Extension.

However, I can't complete the request on my page. Here's a sample of the code I'm using, with Axios (I'm getting the same results using `jQuery.ajax()`):

*edit* OBS: Forgot to mention, we've recently got SSL activated in our account.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Custom-Header, Content-Type',
    },
  };
  axios
    .post(
      'https://cloud.n.<domain>.com/<cloudpageurl>',
      {
        de_name: DATA_EXTENSION_ID,
        email_data: 'test-postman@mail.com',
        PostBody: 'test-postman@mail.com',
      },
      options,
    )
    .then(postData => {
      console.log(postData);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And on the Cloud Page itself, I'm setting these as Headers:

```
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, HEAD, POST");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Custom-Header, Content-Type");
```

Finally, here's the resulting error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.n.<domain>.com/<cloudpageurl>' from origin 'https://www.<mydomain>' has been
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok
status.
```

Comment: Not sure, but a pre-flight request is sent via `OPTIONS` method by the browser. You cloud page does not handle the `OPTIONS` request type, it handles only `POST`.

Comment: Just added it `OPTIONS` and `HEAD`, but it did not solve the issue. Thanks for pointing that out!